# dim everything but selected row ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

How could I easily dim the complementary set of rows, when one gets selected.

Right now I have the code to select a cell so I can call a method on it, but I would like to set opacity of all the other rows.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SummaryCell * selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [selectedCell manageContent];
}
```

Edit: I dont want to iterate through all the other cells (because there will be a lot of them) - wouldn't it be easier to add an UIView above all other cell (this would also prevent user interaction) and place the selected cell above that view (something like increasing z-index in HTML).

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "dim" the other rows. The process to iterate over all visible rows and to set a property on all the rows other than the one selected is as follows:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    for (UITableViewCell *otherCell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        NSIndexPath *otherIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:otherCell];
        if (![indexPath isEqual:otherIndexPath]) { // exclude the selected cell
            // Do whatever you want with otherCell here
        }
    }
}
```

Where my comment is, you can set whatever properties you like on `otherCell`. For example, `otherCell.alpha` which is the alpha (transparency) of that cell.

Comment: Please see my edit about concerns regarding iteration. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The lovely thing about `tableView.visibleCells` is that it is an array of only the **visible** cells. You may have 10,000 rows in your `UITableView`, but you probably only have a handful of those visible at any one time. That's what `tableView.visibleCells` is for. You should have no concerns about iterating over them.

Comment: Thanks ;) 
But again - the problem with this is that when user scrolls down the newly shown cells are undimmed.

Comment: Yes, and you are in complete control of those new cells with cellForRowAtIndexPath, and/or willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Exactly, as Jody says -- once those cells are recycled, you can reset their properties in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate all the visible cells, configure them to be dimmed, then on the datasource cellForIndex method check if there's a selected cell, if there is, check if it is at the asked index, if so configure the cell as selected, if not as dimmed.

Comment: Please see my edit about concerns regarding iteration. Thank you anyway.